# SQL difference in counter between two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like the below:

```
ID,  MachineID     Customer   TimeStamp                     Counter   type
1    A                ABC       2017-10-25 3:08PM              1952      1
2    A                ABC       2017-10-25 3:00PM              1940      1
3    A                ABC      2017-10-25 12:05PM              1920      1
4    A                ABC       2017-10-25 9:00AM              1900      1
5    B                BCD       2017-10-25 3:11PM              1452      1
6    B                BCD       2017-10-25 3:10PM              1440      1
7    B                BCD      2017-10-25 12:15PM              1420      1
8    B                BCD       2017-10-25 9:30AM              1400      1
9    A                ABC       2017-10-23 3:08PM              1900      1
10   A                ABC       2017-10-23 3:00PM              1840      1
11   A                ABC      2017-10-23 12:05PM              1820      1
12   A                ABC       2017-10-23 9:00AM              1800      1
13   B                BCD       2017-10-23 3:11PM              1399      1
14   B                BCD       2017-10-23 3:10PM              1340      1
15   B                BCD      2017-10-23 12:15PM              1320      1
16   B                BCD       2017-10-23 9:30AM              1300      1
```

The counter value increases whenever there is a click. I am  trying to calculate number of clicks for each day by taking maximum counter value at the end of day and subtract the previous day maximum counter value and so on.

How do I do this in SQL server. Have to repeat this for each customer and Machine

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. You mention using the previous days data but all of your sample data is on the same day.

Comment: You could use            select max(Counter) from table1 where convert(varchar(10),timestamp,120) = getdate()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I am using `LAG` function in order to achieve this. You can use `where` clause to filter out specific date you want :

```
Create  table #counter(ID int, timeStamp datetime, Counter int,  type int)
insert into #counter values
(1,   '20171024 3:08PM' ,1952, 1),
(1,   '20171025 3:00PM' ,1964, 1)

Select iq.*, (iq."counter" - iq.yesterday_counter) as today_count
from
(select id, 
        cast("timestamp" as date) as today_date, 
        "counter", 
        LAG("counter") over (order by cast("timestamp" as date)) yesterday_counter 
from #counter
) iq
```

output:

```
id          today_date counter     yesterday_counter today_count
----------- ---------- ----------- ----------------- -----------
1           2017-10-24 1952        NULL              NULL
1           2017-10-25 1964        1952              12
```

Comment: there might be skipping days between so not exactly previous day. Also I have other dimensions like customer name, machine id, I have to do this for each customer and for each machine. I will try this thanks!!

Comment: Did you try putting partition by after over? Eg: `over(partition by col1 order by col2)`

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query to get the max counter for each day is:

```
SELECT CAST(timeStamp as date) AS [dateval]
      ,MAX(Counter) AS [maxCounter]
 FROM YOURDATASET
GROUP BY CAST(timeStamp as date)
```

This is converting the datetime to date- cutting out the time, then taking the max(Counter).

One method to get the difference is to save the result in a temp datastructure, then query it to get the difference.

The question is whether your previous date is exactly the previous day, or if you're skipping days between counts, or taking the weekend off, etc. In that case you have to select the greatest previous date to the date being examined.

ex.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (dateval date, maxCounter int)

INSERT INTO @temp(dateval, maxCounter)
SELECT CAST(timeStamp as date) AS [dateval]
      ,MAX(Counter)
  FROM YOURDATASET
GROUP BY CAST(timeStamp as date)

SELECT T.dateval
      ,T.dateval
       -
       (SELECT maxCounter
          FROM @temp T2
         WHERE T2.dateVal = (SELECT MAX(dateVal)
                               FROM @temp T3
                              WHERE T3.dateVal < T1.dateVal
                            )
       ) AS [Difference]
  FROM @temp T
ORDER BY T.dateval
```

Comment: Yes, there might be skipping days between so not exactly previous day. Also I have other dimensions like customer name, machine id, I have to do this for each customer and for each machine.